# Validate Image width & height before upload in Node, Express With Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am building a project in `Nodejs` with `express` framework & `ejs` as view engine, I am stuck at a point where i need to upload images and i am using `Multer` but the issue is i want to set a criteria where image is not uploaded to server if the image height or width is less than or more than preset size, say `70px * 40Px`, earlier i used to do this seamlessly with codeignitor.

All the solutions i could search for use GM (Graphics Magick) but that comes into play after upload of the image via Multer. I am not looking for code help but any suggestion on any known plugin in npm which can do this for me.

Note : I dont trust on client side validation, even if i use one i still keep server side validation working so i am looking for server side solution for this too.

Comment: You have to either trust the client side validation or allow the image to be uploaded to the server. Can't have it both ways.

Comment: You can however set reasonable limitations on the file size and mime type for the resolution of image you want and then reject it if it doesnt meet the specifications

Comment: @charsi is correct - you can't have it both ways. If you opt for  server side and want a nodejs solution, (i.e. without the GM dependency), to validate the image(s) width/height then take a look at [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp). Accessing the properties mentioned [here](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp#low-level-manipulation) could be utilized to aid validation (i.e. `image.bitmap.width;` and `image.bitmap.height;`).

Comment: i already implemented same with multer & gm and just wrote a code so that if the image is not of desired dimensions it shall automatically delete before sending an error message.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you can read the file into a new IMG element. Then you can check the width & height of the image element.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vz7yjbmf/

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
    var input=this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var x=new Image()
      x.onload=function(){
        alert('width=' + x.width + ', height:' + x.height)
      }
      x.src= e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }      
})
```

Comment: this is client side what about in multer mate?

Comment: @gaurav-komar asked *before upload*, so it must be on the client-side. Before reaching the server.

Comment: very well i guess.